# Print the count of files in a specific format iteratively in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, data-cleaning

I have the following folder structure:

```
A/B/C/D/E/00
A/B/C/D/E/01
.
.
A/B/C/D/E/23
```

Similarly,

```
M/N/O/P/Q/00
M/N/O/P/Q/01
.
.
M/N/O/P/Q/23
```

Now, each folder from 00 to 23 has many files inside, which I would like to count.

If I run this simple command:

```
ls /A/B/C/D/E/00 | wc -l
```

I can get the count of files in each of these sub directories. I want  to automate this or get it iteratively. Can anyone suggest a  way?

Also, the final output I am looking at is a file that should look like this:

```
C E RESULT OF ls /A/B/C/D/E/00 | wc -l RESULT OF ls /A/B/C/D/E/01 | wc -l
M Q RESULT OF ls /M/N/O/P/Q/00 | wc -l RESULT OF ls /M/N/O/P/Q/01 | wc -l
```

So, the output should look like this finally

```
C E 23 23 4 6  7  4 76 98 57 2 67 9 12 34 67 0 2 3  78 98 12 3  57 213
M Q 12 10 2 34 32 1 35 65 87 8 32 2 65 87 98 0 4 12 1  35 34 76 9  67
```

Please note, the values after the alphabets are the values of file counts of the 24 folders 00, 01 through 23.

Using the eval approach: I can hardcode and get the exact results. But, I wanted it in a way that would show me the data for the previous day. So this is what I did:

```
d=`date --date ="1 days ago" +%Y%m%d`
month= `date +%Y%m`
eval echo YZ $d '"$(ls "/A/B/YZ/$month/$d/"'{20150800..20150823})'| wc -l)"'
```

This works perfectly because in the given location there are files inside child directories 20150800,20150801..20150823. However when I try to generalize this like below, it gives me the total count of the folder instead of the count of each sub folder:

```
eval echo YZ $d '"$(ls "/A/B/YZ/$month/$d/"'{"$d"00.."$d"23})'| wc -l)"'
```

Comment: `find` is your friend

Comment: @dawg can you elaborate?

Comment: `find` will allow you to recursively visit all the subdirectories in a tree as you have described. Try that.

Comment: what about `eval echo C E '"$(ls "A/B/C/D/E/"'{00..23}'|wc -l)"'`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, this looks good but I did not want to hard code the vallues C, E , instead it would be great if we can extract it from the directory

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: @jww Not sure why I got a downvote, I asked about how I can approach this situation and posted what I was able to earlier. I dod not ask for any codes. Let me  articulate it better and eddit the question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (not tested):

```
for d in [A-Z]/[A-Z]/[A-Z]/[A-Z]/[A-Z]/[0-9][0-9]
do
  [[ -d $d ]] && echo $d : $(ls $d|wc -l)
done
```

Note that this gives an inccorect line count if one of the file names contains a newline character.